# loading division of webpage in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

My webpage is divided in various parts instead of loading full page, i want to load a part of that page `div id = map_canvas`.

Below code is giving me full page but i want only one part map_canvas

```
public class Jetbill extends Activity {

    public WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jetbill);
         myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         myWebView.loadUrl("http://jetbill.biz/users/login.php");
    }

}
```